# how to fix authentication error while creating database using mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient

var db
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://username:password@ds255588.mlab.com:55588/star-wars-quotes', (err, client) => {
  if (err) return console.log(err)
  db = client.db('starquotes') 
  app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('listening on 3000')
  })
})
```

while run the following code I got a `MongoError: Authentication failed.`
how to fix this error ??!

Comment: Have you checked, that you are using the correct connection string? There might also be missing a `authenticationDatabase`

Comment: yeah I have an error in the name of database and password . it works now